# Which distribution is most similar to a Gaussian but with $[0,\infty)$ support?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, normal-distribution

Which distribution $p$ is most similar to a Gaussian but with $[0,\infty)$ support (i.e., $p(0)=0$)?

Comment: How do you define similar?  A standard Gaussian +$10^{10}$ (truncated at $0$ and scaled up to integrate to $1$ looks very similar.  Simply truncate the Gaussian and double the values is another approach.

Comment: I don't know what that means at all.  I suggested two possibilities.  Which is better?  Why?  What is wrong with each of them?  One has (almost) the same shape but is offset.  One is a scaled version in the region you didn't demand the value be $0$.  If you offer a criterion for similar we may be able to answer.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there a name for the distribution obtained by "trucat[ing] the Gaussian and doubl[ing] the values"?

Comment: I don't know one, but there may well be.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A $\chi^2$ distribution has the required properties, when the mean $k\ge 3$:

[image: χ² distribution]